# Why ajax keeps redirecting to other page after success or error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to ajax and now I want to use ajax so my page does not reload when adding data and displays error or success message. But in implementation, when I submit the form, it redirects me to another page with form validation error/success message. I tried to fix this, but I couldn't find the error. I'm using Jquery 1.8.3 and codeigniter. Here is my code.

Custom.js

```
function tambahBuku() {
$('#form_tambah')[0].reset();
$('#form_tambah').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function() {
var form = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/prjperpus-ci/Table/tambah",
    type: "POST",
    data : form.serialize(), //converting the form data into array and sending it to server
    dataType : "json",
    success:function(response, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("OKAY"); alert(xhr.status);
      if(response.success == true){
            alert("OK");
        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">' +
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
        '<strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span></strong>' + response.messages + '</div>')
      } else{
        if(response.messages instanceof Array){
          $.each(response.messages, function(index,value) {
            alert(index);
          });
        } else {
          alert("OK else");
          $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">' +
          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
          '<strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamination-sign"> </span></strong>' + response.messages + '</div>')
        }
      }
    },   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("ERROR");
            alert(xhr.readyState);
        }
  })
});
```

}

View

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tambah" onclick="tambahBuku()">Tambah Buku</button>
 <div class="messages"></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="tambah" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Input Buku</h3>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
       </div>
             <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'form_tambah','method' => 'POST');
                 echo form_open('Table/tambah', $attributes); ?>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>ISBN</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="ISBN" name="isbn">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Judul Buku</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Judul Buku" name="judul">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
             <?php echo form_close(); ?>
     </div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Controller(Table.php)

```
  public function tambah()
  {
        $data = array(
          'ISBN' => $this->input->post('isbn'),
          'Judul_Buku' => $this->input->post('judul'),
        );

        $config = array(
          array(
            'field' => 'isbn',
            'label' => 'ISBN',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
          ),
          array(
            'field' => 'judul',
            'label' => 'Judul buku',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|is_unique[buku.Judul_Buku]'
          )
       };
         $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

   $validator = array('success' => false , 'messages' => array());
   if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
     $insert_Book = $this->action->insert_record("buku",$data);

     if($insert_Book == true){
        $validator['success'] = true;
        $validator['messages'] = "Data sukses ditambahkan";
        var_dump($validator);
     } else{
       $validator['success'] = false;
       $validator['messages'] = "Data gagal ditambahkan";
     }    
   }else{
     $validator['success'] = false;
     foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
     }
   }
   echo json_encode($validator);
}
```

Model(action.php)

```
public function get_data($table){
      return $this->db->get($table);
}

public function insert_record($table,$data){
  $sql = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
  if($sql === true){
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: the correct syntax for success is `success: function(data, status, xhr) {` ... xhr is 3rd param

Comment: I change that and it's still same

Comment: Please be specific, it's Undefined? Have you tried console loging the xhr param?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ajax to submit your data, you have to stop the HTML from submitting(this is what is causing the redirect).
You can use the preventDefault method of the event object in the submit handler to accomplish this.

```
$('#form_tambah').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: why its keep showing form validation error and why xhr.status undefined in success condition.

Comment: {"success":false,"messages":{"isbn":"
The ISBN field is required.<\/p>","judul":"
The Judul buku field is required.<\/p>", it return echo json_encode($validator); in controller

Comment: xhr.status return 200 in header, but it return undefined when I try to alert(xhr.status) in success condition

Comment: Might be a stupid question but are the fields filled in when you submit? Also I'm not sure you noticed but you are resseting the forms before submitting.... Hence no values

Comment: above example if I don't fill any fields in form, if I fill my data added but it redirect to another page and echo json_encode($validator). and it's sometimes return judul buku must contain unique value but data added in database. It's very complicated issues for beginner like me

Comment: If you don't fill any fields then it makes sense that you get validation errors as you have specified your fields as required... It sounds like your code is functioning as expected aside from the xhr but that isn't really required anyways. Just put in the preventDefault and the page shouldn't redirect.

Comment: okay it's done about not redirect page. But why my data not increase after that, it required me to reload first.